# C++ Multiple enum elements being passed as parameter?

Tags: c++, enums

I've been trying to figure this portion of C++ code I'm converting over to JAVA. The method call `PrintItem()` takes in `DWORD` as a second parameter, but in this particular example it allows two elements from the `enum` at once?

I was refering to the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874051/c-multiple-enums-in-one-function-argument-using-bitwise-or) by [Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303986/ashish) to try and get some clarification but it didn't help much.

```
enum
    {
        PRINT_ENTRY         = 0x0001,
        PRINT_PREPEND       = 0x0002,
        PRINT_APPEND        = 0x0004,
        PRINT_PRECOMMENTS   = 0x0008,
        PRINT_POSTCOMMENTS  = 0x0010,
        PRINT_SPECIAL       = 0x0010,
        PRINT_DEFAULT       = PRINT_ENTRY | PRINT_PREPEND | PRINT_APPEND | PRINT_PRECOMMENTS | PRINT_POSTCOMMENTS | PRINT_SPECIAL
    };
```

The method call with two enum elements being passed in? This is what I don't understand.

`bResult = PrintItem( pMergeItem, PRINT_PREPEND | PRINT_ENTRY );`

Method declaration

`bool PrintItem( CItem* pItem, DWORD options = PRINT_DEFAULT );`

And the Definition, trimmed down a bit:

```
// Prints an individual item to the invoice (based on appropriate template settings)
bool CPrintRptInvoice::PrintItem( CItem* pItem, DWORD options )
{
    bool bResult = true;
    CString strKey = GetItemKey( pItem );

    DWORD getOpts = CPrintTemplate::GE_NONE;
    if ( options & PRINT_ENTRY )
        getOpts |= CPrintTemplate::GE_ENTRY;
    if ( options & PRINT_PREPEND )
        getOpts |= CPrintTemplate::GE_PREPEND;
    if ( options & PRINT_APPEND )
        getOpts |= CPrintTemplate::GE_APPEND;

    CString strEntry = m_pTemplate->GetEntry( strKey, getOpts );

    // print any prefix first
    if ( options & PRINT_PRECOMMENTS ) 
        PrintComment( pItem->GetInvoicePrefix() );

    // print main entry
    if ( strEntry.IsEmpty() )
    {
        if ( ( options & PRINT_ENTRY ) && !m_pTemplate->EntryExists( strKey ) )
        {
            //Code to print Entries, not touching options anymore.
        }
    }

    // print any special cases
    if ( bResult && ( options & PRINT_SPECIAL ) )
    {
        //Code to print special cases, not touching options anymore...
    }

    // print any suffix last
    if ( options & PRINT_POSTCOMMENTS ) 
        PrintComment( pItem->GetInvoiceSuffix() );

    return bResult;
}
```

My question is - How is it dealing with multiple parameters of enum? I don't see it handling any of that in that method definition! What i trimmed out doesn't touch `options` at all.

I guess I'm confused because I see `options` as a collection of some sort, no? So, how is it that you can do this and just get the right element: `if ( options & PRINT_PRECOMMENTS )`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a bitwise `OR`, which allows to combine more than one enum value into the integer which is is, internally (so still just one argument in the function call). Such enums are also called a flagset. They are usually characterized by members that have values which represent just one bit: a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8, e = 16, ... so they can be combined; `a | b` is 3 when casted to int.
Inside the function body, individual flags are then queried separately using the bitwise `&` operator.

additional reference: [How to use enums as flags in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448396/how-to-use-enums-as-flags-in-c)

btw. this concept seems to be quite similar in Java: [Implementing a bitfield using java enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346477/implementing-a-bitfield-using-java-enums)

Comment: Thank you, You broke it down nicely. I guess I had a hard time finding out information on this since i wasn't sure what it was called, Works fine in Java!